# Random Unicode text in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode, cloudflare, w3-total-cache

[image: page screenshot]

This is what happens when I first load my wordpress pages. When I refresh the page it correctly load the page.

I'm using cloudflare and w3 total cache. I cleared it and it works fine for the logged in user. But when I tried it in other browsers the issue is still there.

Update from hosting support

This issue was caused by an error in the Advance Cache file created by W3 Total Cache.

At this time, I have disabled this file. In time, W3TC will create a new file and it should not cause this issue again.

...

After I disabled W3 Total Cache this error is fixed. Is there anyway to use w3 Total Cache without this error?

Comment: This is lot of detective work ahead of you. Try deactivating some plugins, prefferably in order you added them. That would be number 1. If that does not help, you have to post a lot of other details, like encoding of your files and database

Comment: @PavelJanicek updated question with hosting support update